# WPF Threads block the MainWindow.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm working on a project where almost nothing should be async and everything should be instant.

I'm using `BackgroundWorker`to separate the threads and do the work that I need. When everything is done I'm showing results in `MainWindow.xaml` like this:

```
  private void Result()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                txbDistanza.Text = misura.GetMisura(GlobalVariables.Base, 
                                       GlobalVariables.Misura).ToString();;
            });
   }
```

Doing this, the `MainWindow.xaml` seems bloced and when I'm trying to move the Window, its not moving.

This is the constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };
            bgWorker.DoWork += ResetAll;
            bgWorker.ProgressChanged += ResetAll_ProgressStatus;
        }
```

And this is where all thing get done:

```
 private void ResetAll(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                method1();
                method2();
                method3();
                method4();
                method5();
                method6();
                method7();   
             }
                if (dotIndicatorTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                    break;

                Result();
         }
```

I can't get why the `MainWindow.xaml` is blocked when I start up the project.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Be aware that `misura.GetMisura` is called in the UI thread. In case it is a long running operation, the UI will obviously be blocked.

Comment: Also note that `while (true)` without `break` is an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, it shoul be infinite loop, i need to interogate. Maybe its not he best way..

Comment: `if (dotIndicatorTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)` is never reached.

Comment: im guessing that `this.Dispatcher.Invoke` is a control which means it  executes on the UI thread and will hang it until its done

Comment: @Clemens how to show the value in UI without blocking it ?

Comment: You don't seem to be running your backgroundworker. How long does each loop take to run?  Put a stopwatch in there. If it's like 10 milliseconds then that'd be a problem. I think you should have some delay between loops eg using await task delay.  Rather than updating ui directly i would bind.  Update a viewmodel property that uses inotifypropertychanged to notify a bound ui property of change. That notification should be ok from a background thread because it's marshalled automatically. But if you're using dispatcher use invokeasync.